# In python, how would I open a PIL or Imagemagick Image as a file

Tags: python, file-io, amazon-s3, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I'm taking uploaded files which I can save to S3 using SimpleS3:

```
from simples3.bucket import S3Bucket
upload = request.POST['image']
s = S3Bucket("cdn", s3.access_key, s3.secret_key)
s.put(upload.filename, upload.file.read())
```

Somewhere between saving that as a file and uploading it I save the file which is an image as a thumbnail using PIL or Imagemagick depending on what kind of image file was uploaded. The process there is to turn the File into an Image. My question is how do I open that Image as a file? I'm trying to upload the thumbnail to Amazon's S3 exactly as I do above. My code below is the idea of what I'm attempting:

```
thumb = self._im.copy() #where _im is the Image
s = S3Bucket("cdn", s3.access_key, s3.secret_key)
s.put(self.filename+ext, thumb)
```

I've tried with no success:

```
f = open(thumb, "rb")
s.put(self.filename+ext, f.read()
```

What does work, but is incredibly inefficient, is writing the file to the drive using the Image.save function and then opening it as a file:

```
thumb.save(self.filename+ext)
f = open(self.filename+ext, 'r')
s.put(self.filename+ext, f.read())
```

Comment: Figured it out:

    from StringIO import StringIO
    f = StringIO()
    thumb.save(f, ext)
    s.put(self.filename+ext, f.getvalue())

Comment: its a good idea to post this as an answer and mark it correct in case someone else comes across the same problem.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours after posting

Comment: Sorry! I had forgotten about the new user restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
f = StringIO() 
thumb.save(f, ext) 
s.put(self.filename+ext, f.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 0):

For ImageMagick case, if you are using PythonMagick, you can use underlying Blob class,

```
>>> from PythonMagick import Image, Blob
>>> image = Image("images/test_image.miff")
>>> image.magick("PNG")
>>> blob = Blob()
>>> image.write(blob)
>>> len(blob.data)
28282
>>> blob.data[0:20]
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x94'
```